# Django Rest Framework does not show content from StreamField

Tags: django, wagtail, django-rest-framework

I have a model class with ModelChooserBlock inside StreamField and If I open my Django Rest Framework I don't get a satisfactory result. Specifically "Ingredient" should have a link to ingredients or directly Database.

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "id": 1,
    "meta": {
        "type": "cultinadb.Menu",
        "detail_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/menu/1/"
    },
    "title": "",
    "Ingredient": [
        {
            "type": "zutaten",
            "value": 2,
            "id": "647d762f-ec26-4c78-928a-446344b1cb8a"
        },
        {
            "type": "zutaten",
            "value": 1,
            "id": "6ab4e425-5e75-4ec0-ba63-8e7899af95e2"
        }
    ],
}
```

Here is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.api import APIField
from wagtailmodelchooser import register_model_chooser
from wagtailmodelchooser.blocks import ModelChooserBlock

@register_model_chooser
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    picture_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    translate_url = models.URLField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

@register_model_chooser
class Menu(models.Model):
    Ingredient = StreamField([
        ('zutaten', ModelChooserBlock('kitchen.Ingredient')) ],
        null=True, verbose_name='', blank=True)

    panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [ StreamFieldPanel('Ingredient') ],
            heading="Zutaten", classname="col5"
        ),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    api_fields = [
        APIField('Ingredient'),
    ]
```

[I tried to add it as shown here](https://github.com/datalets/blemmy/blob/0a7b7f7cdefa4b32cca6c04b3e58db67d09b6390/openfarms/models/models.py#L129) with serializer, but then I got errors.
I created serializer.py and added this code

```
class MenuRenditionField(Field):
    def get_attribute(self, instance):
        return instance
    def to_representation(self, menu):
        return OrderedDict([
            ('title', menu.Ingredient.name),
            ('imageurl', menu.Ingredient.picture_url),
            ('imageurl', menu.Ingredient.translate_url),
        ])
```

Then i changed my api_fields like this

```
api_fields = [
   APIField('Ingredient', serializer=MenuRenditionField()),
]
```

The error that I get when adding this code.

```
AttributeError at /api/v2/menu/1/
'StreamValue' object has no attribute 'name'
   Request Method:  GET
   Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/menu/1/
   Django Version:  1.11.1
   Exception Type:  AttributeError
   Exception Value: 
   'StreamValue' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I will be very grateful for the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customise the API output of a StreamField block by overriding the `get_api_representation` method. In this case, it might look something like:

```
class IngredientChooserBlock(ModelChooserBlock):
    def get_api_representation(self, value, context=None):
        if value:
            return {
                'id': value.id,
                'name': value.name,
                # any other relevant fields of your model...
            }
```

Then use `IngredientChooserBlock('kitchen.Ingredient')` in place of `ModelChooserBlock('kitchen.Ingredient')` in your StreamField definition.

Comment: It works!! Thank you very much! @gasman
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvXVO.png

Comment: Hey @gasman Thank you for your help, actually you did it for me two times.
this code works well, but it can't represent dataset from StreamField for examle i have 

`ingredient = StreamField([
        ('zutaten', IngredientChooserBlock('kitchen.Ingredient')) ],
        null=True, verbose_name='', blank=True)`

and it prints out an error in DRF like this
 
`Object of type 'StreamValue' is not JSON serializable`

Comment: @khashashin From that error, it sounds like you're returning a complex object somewhere in the `get_api_representation` response, such as returning `value` instead of `value.name` etc - DRF can only work with simple Python types such as strings, lists and dicts. I'd need to see the full code to investigate further, though - I'd suggest opening as a new question.

Comment: thanks @gasman I created a new topic [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45934876/converting-class-object-to-readable-value-for-get-api-representation-function)