# Converting class object to readable value for get_api_representation function

Tags: django, wagtail, django-rest-framework, wagtail-streamfield

[Previous topic where I was kindly helped by @gasman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843298/django-rest-framework-does-not-show-content-from-streamfield/45844215?noredirect=1#comment78805632_45844215)
so i have a model class ingredients like:

```
@register_model_chooser
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and to represent this in API i created this class:

```
class IngredientChooserBlock(ModelChooserBlock):
    def get_api_representation(self, value, context=None):
        if value:
            return {
                'name': value.name,
            }
```

then i have another model class that uses `IngredientChooserBlock` class:

```
@register_model_chooser
class Menu(models.Model):
    ingredient = StreamField([
        ('zutaten', IngredientChooserBlock('kitchen.Ingredient')) ],
        null=True, verbose_name='', blank=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

and because i need this `ingredient` in my API i created same model class to overwrite `get_api_representation`:

```
class WeekChooserBlock(ModelChooserBlock):
    def get_api_representation(self, value, context=None):
        if value:
            return {
                'ingredients': value.ingredient,
            }
```

and in the end in my main model class I'm trying to use this `WeekChooserBlock` which takes `kitchen.Menu` as argument like so:

```
class Week(models.Model):
    dishes_sp = StreamField([
        ('menu', WeekChooserBlock('kitchen.Menu')) ],
        null=True, verbose_name='', blank=True)
```

The problem is that it prints out an error in DRF like this:

```
Object of type 'StreamValue' is not JSON serializable
```

[image]

---

Didn't want to create too big question, but for greater clarity i have actually another objects in my `Menu` class like:

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    ingredient = StreamField([
        ('zutaten', IngredientChooserBlock('kitchen.Ingredient')) ],
        null=True, verbose_name='', blank=True)
    steps = StreamField([
        ('Schritt', TextBlock())
        ], null=True, verbose_name='Vorbereitungsschritte', blank=True)
```

and I'm also trying to represent them too. But the error is displayed only if I'm trying to output `StreamField`

```
class WeekChooserBlock(ModelChooserBlock):
    def get_api_representation(self, value, context=None):
        if value:
            return {
                'title': value.title,
                'picture': value.image,
                'price': value.price,
                'ingredients': value.ingredient,
                'steps': value.steps
            }
```

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're returning `{'ingredients': value.ingredient}` from `WeekChooserBlock.get_api_representation`. Here `value.ingredient` is a StreamValue instance, which is a complex Wagtail-specific object containing methods for template rendering, as well as the actual stream data - DRF doesn't know how to handle this complex object.

You need to ensure that your `get_api_representation` response only consists of standard Python types, such as strings and dicts. For example:

```
class WeekChooserBlock(ModelChooserBlock):
    def get_api_representation(self, value, context=None):
        if value:
            return {
                'ingredients': [ingredient.value['name'] for ingredient in value.ingredient],
            }
```

If you want to re-use the API representation for Ingredient that you defined in `IngredientChooserBlock.get_api_representation`, it gets a bit tricker, but you should be able to do this with:

```
class WeekChooserBlock(ModelChooserBlock):
    def get_api_representation(self, value, context=None):
        if value:
            ingredient = value.ingredient
            return ingredient.stream_block.get_api_representation(ingredient, context=context)
```

Comment: I tried with the code that you gave, but still produces an errors.
You forgot to insert model class object between `value` and `.stream_block`
enyway i get errors:
`return value.stream_block.get_api_representation(value,context=context)`
or:
`return value.ingredient.stream_block.get_api_representation(value,context=context)`
 --- `'Menu' object is not iterable` if I'm trying to return this without `ingredient` I'm get: `'Menu' object has no attribute 'stream_block'`

Comment: so for another users 
I tried the second part of the tip 
`class WeekChooserBlock(ModelChooserBlock):
    def get_api_representation(self, value, context=None):
        if value:
            ingredient = value.ingredient
            return ingredient.stream_block.get_api_representation(ingredient, context=context)` and its works for me